# Создавать листы и возвращать используя raw_input - Python

Tags: python, list

А как таким образом можно присвоить имя листу, например или переменной?

Ввожу имя переменной, которое мне нужно. Это имя я буду использовать для имени листа

```
name of your list=raw_input("Enter name of your list:")
```

Я хотел бы для нового листа, который является копией созданного листа **a** задать имя через клавиатуру, введя его предварительно в raw_input. А сам лист **a** получается у меня через операции в бесконечном while True

```
"сюда я хочу вставить то  что ввожу в raw_input"=a[:]
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, переформулируйте и приведите готовый пример того чего хотите, что ли

Comment: @andreymal возможно автор имеет ввиду: `namespace[raw_input("enter name"]=a` где `namespace=globals()` (с locals() не обязано работать) —не рекомендуемая опция в обоих случаях. Необходимо отредактировать вопрос и больше контекста добавить: что конкретно и главное *зачем* вы хотите сделать. Похоже на [XY-задачу](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044)

Answer (score 1):

> Мне нужно задать имя листу через raw_input ... Каждый раз через while - я
>   получаю новый лист и результат хотел бы сохранять ввводя имя листа как
>   переменной, чтобы на нее ссылаться.

Чтобы каждому списку дать своё имя,  можно словарь в Питоне использовать:

```
import sys

lists = {} # name -> list
while not enough(lists):
    name = raw_input("Enter list name")
    if valid(name):
        lists[name] = get_new_list()
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, "invalid name %r. Try again." % name
```

Опции типа: `exec "{name} = get_new_list()".format(**vars())` следует избегать.

Comment: Ваш код не сработал.))  enough - это какая-то функция. В любом случае имя будет валидным, если оно не дублируется с другим.

Comment: @AlexSkys мой ответ: используйте словарь, а код это просто пример как словарь можно использовать: буквально он естественно не работает (подразумевается вы свой код подставляеете вместо `enough()`, `valid()`, `get_new_list()` функций).

Comment: Ваша идея со словарем кажется мне более убедительной. Спасибо, я попробую

Answer (score -1):

```
name = raw_input("Enter the name: ")
a =  list()
name = a
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = input("Enter name of your list:")
globals()[a] = list(a)
print('< %s >' % test)
```

out:

```
Enter name of your list:test
< ['t', 'e', 's', 't'] >
```

Comment: Нужен комментарий к коду

Comment: Мне нужно задать имя листу через raw_input . Так-то получается, что имя name стало глобальным в посте выше. Каждый раз через while - я получаю новый лист и результат хотел бы сохранять ввводя имя листа как переменной, чтобы на нее ссылаться.

Comment: код делает именно то о чем вы пишете, сохраняет лист с именем, введенным в input. или вы не обратили внимание на переменную test в которой лежит list